# My application fails to create MAPI/Messaging profile properly using MAPI subsystem

Tags: com, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-2007, mapi

I have an application which creates a MAPI profile to send mails/messages. The profile is getting created properly on Outlook2007 environment, but it is not getting created properly on Outlook2007 SP2 environment. Both the source code and "exchange environment to which MAPI/outlook profile" are same. The profile is created using MAPI subsystem.

Description about the application: The application is a windows service-based application. The service executes a COM application. The COM application spawns a new thread to create a new profile and sends a sample message.

Actual problem: During the profile creation, the call to the ConfigureMsgService function (that belongs to IMsgServiceAdmin) is not working properly even though it returns S_OK. The value for the 5th parameter "lpProps" of ConfigureMsgService function is given below.

```
    // First, the mailbox name.
    ZeroMemory(&rgval[0], sizeof(SPropValue) );
    rgval[0].ulPropTag = PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_NAME; 
    rgval[0].Value.lpszA = szMailbox;

    // Next, the server name.
    ZeroMemory(&rgval[1], sizeof(SPropValue) );
    rgval[1].ulPropTag = PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_SERVER;
    rgval[1].Value.lpszA = szServer;

    // For NT Services, need to do this to keep MAPI from
    // displaying dialog boxes.
    ZeroMemory(&rgval[2], sizeof(SPropValue) );
    rgval[2].ulPropTag = PR_CONVERSION_PROHIBITED;  //As the com application is executed by the NT service, this parameter is specified.
    rgval[2].Value.b = TRUE;
```

Also note, prior to ConfigureMsgService function call, all the other MAPI calls such as MAPIInitialize, MAPIAdminProfiles, CreateProfile, AdminServices, CreateMsgService, GetMsgServiceTable etc are succeeded.

My question, the same code was working properly with Outlook 2007 environment, but it failed in Outlook 2007 SP2 environment.

Please note,
1. when the same code is executed from a stand-alone application, it worked fine.
2. The code didn't work properly if the service is executed as a Local System account or as a network service account.

1. What could be the problem? Am I missing some thing.
2. Is there any work-around is available?

Thanks in advance
Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in #2 of your note:

> Please note, 1. when the same code is
>   executed from a stand-alone
>   application, it worked fine. 2. The
>   code didn't work properly if the
>   service is executed as a **Local System
>   account or as a network service
>   account**.

MAPI profiles are stored in the current user's hive* in the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKEY_USERS{user SID}).  The system accounts (LocalSystem and NetworkService) don't present a user hive which MAPI needs to write the profile information.

The easiest fix is to have your service run under a user account which has been granted the Log On As Service right.  Depending on how your COM app is run as (in proc vs out of proc) you may be able to have it run as a specific user instead of a system account.

*Hive is the term used for the different sections of the registry. Here we're just dealing with the user's own section of the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I tried your idea, but it doesn't worked. I spoke to Microsoft in this case, they have provided a fix for this issue(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972363), it fixed it.

Saravanan